# Outer Column reference in an aggregate function of a cross apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, outer-apply

In my query, I am using `OUTER APPLY` to get employee count in different scenarios like

1. Number of Employees Joined in each day of a period
2. Number of Employees Resigned in each day of a period
3. Number of employees leave on each day of a period... etc

Expected output (`From:2017-01-10 to 2017-01-12` ) is

```
CDATE       TOTAL_COUNT JOIN_COUNT  RESIGNED _COUNT ...
2017-01-10  1204        10          2
2017-01-11  1212        5           1
2017-01-12  1216        3           0
```

Below is my query

```
DECLARE @P_FROM_DATE    DATE = '2017-01-01', --From 1st Jan
        @P_TO_DATE      DATE = '2017-01-10'  --to 10th jan

;WITH CTE_DATE
AS
(   
    SELECT  @P_FROM_DATE    AS CDATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(DAY,1,CDATE)
    FROM    CTE_DATE
    WHERE   DATEADD(DAY,1,CDATE)    <=  @P_TO_DATE
)
SELECT  [CDATE]
        ,[TOTAL_COUNT]
        ,[JOIN_COUNT]
FROM    CTE_DATE
OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN [EMP_DOJ]  = [CDATE] THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [JOIN_COUNT]
                ,COUNT(*)   AS  [TOTAL_COUNT]
                ,....
                ,...
        FROM    [EMPLOYEE_TABLE]
        )   AS  D
```

But while executing my query, getting the below error.

> Msg 8124, Level 16, State 1, Line 18 Multiple columns are specified in
>   an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an
>   expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that
>   outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression.

Here the column `[JOIN_COUNT]` only producing the error, without this column the query is working. But i have more column pending to add like `[JOIN_COUNT]` (eg  Resigned_Count, ...etc )

Comment: Is this in one of the pieces of SQL you are not showing us?   The .... parts?

Comment: it seems to be related to this http://sqlmag.com/blog/aggregates-outer-reference - their SQL also looked reasonable - could you perform each employee count as a separate section of the WITH statement, then SELECT a grand query of them at the end?

Comment: @Cato, if i remove the 'COUNT(CASE WHEN [EMP_DOJ] = [CDATE] THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [JOIN_COUNT]', i will get the query executed with the expected output. But JOIN_COUNT only the error (but i have more columns pending like this JOIN_COUNT, as RESIGN_COUNT, JUNIOR_JOIN_COUNT '...

Answer (score 1):

You do not need an `outer apply` to achieve this, simply join your `CTE_DATE` valus to your employee table and use a `sum(case when <Conditions met> then 1 else 0 end)` with a `group by` the `CDate`

```
select d.CDate
      ,sum(case when e.Emp_DoJ <= d.CDate
                  and e.EmployeeResignDate > d.CDate
                then 1
                else 0
                end) as Total_Count

      ,sum(case when e.Emp_DoJ = d.CDate
                then 1
                else 0
                end) as Join_Count

      ,sum(case when e.EmployeeResignDate = d.CDate
                then 1
                else 0
                end) as Resign_Count
from CTE_DATE d
    left join Employee_Table e
        on(d.CDate between e.Emp_DoJ and e.EmployeeResignDate)
group by d.CDate
order by d.CDate
```